# adding the right index to a table in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, optimization, ubuntu

We are having a big problem of high CPU usage of MySQL process in our database server, after investigation we have found that a big part of slow queries are related to a specific table and a big number of queries have the same structure just the field targetPk is changing from query to another

```
SELECT  item_t1.PK  
FROM product2division item_t0 
JOIN division item_t1 ON  item_t0.SourcePK = item_t1.PK  
WHERE ( item_t0.Qualifier  = 'Product2Division' 
   AND  item_t0.TargetPK  = 8799116853249 
   AND  item_t0.LanguagePK  IS NULL) 
   AND (item_t1.TypePkString=8796130967634 ) 
order by  item_t0.RSequenceNumber  ASC , item_t0.PK  ASC
```

running

```
explain 
SELECT  item_t1.PK  
FROM product2division item_t0 
JOIN division item_t1 ON  item_t0.SourcePK = item_t1.PK  
WHERE ( item_t0.Qualifier  = 'Product2Division' 
   AND  item_t0.TargetPK  = 8799116853249 
   AND  item_t0.LanguagePK  IS NULL) 
   AND (item_t1.TypePkString=8796130967634 ) 
order by  item_t0.RSequenceNumber  ASC , item_t0.PK  ASC \G
```

i get this result :

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: item_t0
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: linksource_20002,qualifier_20002,linktarget_20002
          key: qualifier_20002
      key_len: 767
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: item_t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: hybris.item_t0.SourcePK
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

the output of MySQLtunner
[image]

i don't want to do any move before being sure about what i'm doing , do you think adding an index in the column item_t0.TargetPK will optimize the queries, as it is the one who is changing value from query to another ? or something else ?

**Update**

i know i had to do that before, but i figured out that the index targetPk is already implemented

i don't know what to do next ! **HEALP**

```
*************************** 6. row ***************************
        Table: product2division
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: linktarget_20002
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: TargetPK
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 0
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

here are all indexes in  the product2division table :

```
 Key_name: linktarget_20002
 Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: TargetPK

 Key_name: qualifier_20002
 Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: Qualifier

 Key_name: seqnr_20002
 Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: SequenceNumber

 Key_name: rseqnr_20002
 Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: RSequenceNumber

 Key_name: linksource_20002
 Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: SourcePK

 Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
 Column_name: PK
```

**show create table output**

```
mysql> show create table product2division \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: product2division
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `product2division` (
  `hjmpTS` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `TypePkString` bigint NOT NULL,
  `PK` bigint NOT NULL,
  `createdTS` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifiedTS` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnerPkString` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `aCLTS` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `propTS` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `Qualifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `SourcePK` bigint NOT NULL,
  `TargetPK` bigint NOT NULL,
  `RSequenceNumber` int DEFAULT '0',
  `SequenceNumber` int DEFAULT '0',
  `languagepk` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `sealed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`),
  KEY `linksource_20002` (`SourcePK`),
  KEY `rseqnr_20002` (`RSequenceNumber`),
  KEY `seqnr_20002` (`SequenceNumber`),
  KEY `qualifier_20002` (`Qualifier`),
  KEY `linktarget_20002` (`TargetPK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**second table**

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE division \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: division
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `division` (
  `hjmpTS` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `TypePkString` bigint NOT NULL,
  `PK` bigint NOT NULL,
  `createdTS` datetime NOT NULL,
  `p_isconstruction` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

my.cnf file attributes :

```
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 3
innodb_fast_shutdown            = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 7168M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_log_file_size            = 512M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
join_buffer_size                = 8M
max_connections                 = 250
max_heap_table_size             = 48M
sort_buffer_size                = 48M
table_definition_cache          = 600
thread_cache_size               = 8
thread_stack                    = 192K
tmp_table_size                  = 64M
wait_timeout                    = 28800

# * MyISAM settings
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP
read_buffer_size                = 4M
low_priority_updates            = 1
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 1M
key_buffer_size                 = 16M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet              = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer                      = 16M
```

**RAM CPU and swap usage**
[image]

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You must provide CREATE TABLE for both tables. At least...

Comment: Does `PK` imply `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 2):

I will be concerned on cnf options only.

This four options are not related to the storage engines but to the client's sessions so my advise is to keep them in a separate paragraph of the cnf file. Their values combined and multiplied by the number of concurrent connections (max possible and max reached) impact the RAM consumption.

```
read_buffer_size                = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 1M
join_buffer_size                = 8M
sort_buffer_size                = 48M
```

48M is pretty big value for sort buffer. Probably you don't need it that large. You can start with 1M value for each of that variables. That will lead to 4M (~5M with overheads) buffers for each connection (instead of 77M now) and will decrease the RAM consumption by 5GB reached/18GB max.

Also that variable is too high for your hardware:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 7168M
```

You have 7.8GB of total RAM that is shared by OS, DB and other services on the host. The good starting point for that value is a half of total RAM amount or 4G.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 4G
```

Keep in mind that `innodb_log_file_size` value should be close to 1/8 of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value. Its current value of 512M is good enough.

Approximate mysql RAM consumption then will be
4G + (75 * 5M) = 5G (expected)
4G + (250 * 5M) = 6G (maximum)
And 2-3G are free for OS needs and fine tuning. If your RAM consumption will be low enough you can tune your options starting with `innodb_buffer_pool_size` - make it 5G big instead of 4G with `innodb_log_file_size` corrected respectively.

You can refer to the `InnoDB metrics` section of the mysqltuner's report to see `InnoDB buffer pool / data size` ratio. If data size is close to or bigger than physical RAM you have then you will not gain too much from `innodb_buffer_pool_size` modification. But I see you have no slow queries and tmp tables so it wouldn't be a problem for you.

You can raise join/sort/read/rnd buffer values instead up to 6-8MB in total. Which values need to be increased depends on your queries and should be tested inplace.

Comment: Thank you for your time i appreciate, [OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 7.0G/70.1M from mysqltunner

Comment: With this ratio, changing the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5G will help ?

Comment: Having 70M of data you can set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 1GB (if your database have no tend to grow up) and then set your read/rnd/join/sort buffers to 4M each. 70M data is small enough to fit into RAM entirely so you will not suffer of disk i/o. I hope you haven't used MyISAM tables intensively.

Comment: yes, we have just innoDB

Comment: So 1G for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and 128M for `innodb_log_file_size` will be sufficient until your DB grows to 400MB+

Comment: Can this exist configuration cause the high CPU usage by MySQL ? or just as a best practice, using what you recommend ?

Comment: @HamzaAZIZ - "High CPU" almost always means inadequate indexes or poor formulation of queries.  (My Answer tries to address those.)

Comment: Under certain circumstances the lack of RAM can lead to the intensive swapping and a huge overhead will be added to a regular operations. Say, for `vmstat` command `wa` value (standing for iowait) can become above 50% of CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

"do you think adding an index in the column item_t0.TargetPK will optimize the queries, as it is the one who is changing value from query to another ?"

That is a bad reason for indexing.

What matters is how much the index will help reduce the amount of work required to compute the query. Whether your proposed index will help will mostly depend on which of these results is larger:

```
select count(*) from product2division item_t0  where item_t0.Qualifier  = 'Product2Division'
select count(*) from product2division item_t0  where item_t0.TargetPK  = 8799116853249
```

Assuming there is even distribution of `TargetPk` values.

If `TargetPK` is unqique then the second query will always return 1 (or zero) which means there will only be a maximum of 1 row to look at in the table which is great.

Of course, if the difference is small then the decider will be down to how clustered the rows that match these filters are. If both counts are relatively high, then maybe a composite index which includes both columns could be a good idea (if there's not a lot of crossover on the rows that each filter finds).

Another possibility is that you could drive the query from the `division` table. This could be sensible if the `TypePkString` is going to return a small amount of rows and the `SourcePK` filter (from the join) is also relatively good at reducing the number of rows visited in `product2division`. For this order of tables, you would be indexing:

```
division (TypePkString)
product2division (SourcePK)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i run the mentioned queries, there are 1291569 rows for the first count (select count(*) from product2division item_t0  where item_t0.Qualifier  = 'Product2Division') and 13 for the other, what do you think about that ?

Comment: What do you think? I think that visiting ~1.3 million rows via an index is going to be a lot slower than visiting 13 rows no matter how clustered they are. I would expect (so long as the MySQL optimizer also believes so) that you will get substantially faster execution time with the suggested index (certainly in the milliseconds as long as you aren't on old hard drives with not enough memory)

Comment: i forget to add the output of MySQLtunner, could you please check if it is more related to physical resources (RAM), or queries optimization, i'm stuck on this issue more than a week

Comment: Even if you add a ton of RAM, this query will be slow using the existing query. The new index will be almost a million times faster without any changes to hardware.

Comment: You mean adding index as the column item_t0.TargetPK or sourcePk?

Comment: TargetPK. You can run similar queries to figure out how effective driving the query from `division` is - you haven't shared anything here. That said, adding two indexes is more expensive than adding one, and adding one will almost certainly make your query fast enough.

Comment: Okay i will try this and keep you updated, Thanks a lot for the time

Comment: i know i had to do that before sorry, i figured out that the index targetPk is already implemented

Comment: The Optimizer will pick which of those 3 single-column indexes has the best cardinality.  So most of your analysis is good for theory and not relevant to what can be done by the user to speed up the query.  When you have 3 columns tested with `=` (or `IS NULL`), a composite index of all 3 will virtually always be the winner.

Comment: MySQL almost always usings only a single index in a single `SELECT`.  The reason for providing multiple indexes is to give the Optimizer some choices -- it can see (to some extent) the cardinality and choose dynamically which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Add these composite indexes:

```
item_t0:  INDEX(Qualifier, TargetPK, LanguagePK)
item_t1:  INDEX(TypePkString, PK)
```

It sounds like you currently have `INDEX(Qualifier)`?  If so, remove it as redundant.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Datatypes, engines, indexes, etc are important for query optimization.

The formula used for "memory usage" is pessimistic.  It may not be as bad as it sounds.  The real question is -- if you are swapping, then something is configured too high.  For further analysis, please provide the info requested here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

The number of "joins without index" does not sound very high, once it is divided by the Uptime (more than a year).

The `EXPLAIN` shows "Rows: 1" for each table.  The speed must be only a few milliseconds.  Or was it using only a subset of the real data?

See also my [*index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) It takes much of the guessing and `COUNTing` out of building the best index for simple cases.

**More** (based on added info)

This change may avoid swapping, which will help speed:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 7168M --> 5G
```

Possibly excessive:

```
max_connections                 = 250
```

Use `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';` to see how much of that 250 was actually needed since the last startup.  Then lower `max_connections` to something realistic, but safe.

`BIGINT` takes 8 bytes, `INT` takes 4 bytes, other ints take even less.  The table sizes could shrink if you consistently changed each element (TargetPK, LanguagePK, etc) across the tables.  `LanguagePK` could probably be 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (range: 0..255), thereby saving 7 bytes per use.  Smaller --> a little faster, less disk space needed, less buffer_pool needed, etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128272/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-adding-the-right-index-to-a-table-in-a-mysql).